# django-models,views.py & templates to foreign key assignment

Tags: python, mysql, django

models.py

```
class Author(models.Model):
    author_id=models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=40)
    email = models.EmailField()
    age=models.IntegerField()

    class Meta:
    db_table=u'Author Info'

    def __unicode__(self):
        return u"%d %s %s %s %d" % (self.pk, self.first_name, self.last_name, self.email,self.age)

    def books(self):
        return Book.objects.filter(author=self)

class Book(models.Model):
    book_id=models.AutoField(primary_key=True,unique=True)
    book_name=models.CharField(max_length=30)
    publisher_name=models.CharField(max_length=40)
    author=models.ForeignKey(Author)

    class Meta:
        db_table = u'Book Name'

    def __unicode__(self):
        return u'%d %s %s' % (self.pk, self.book_name, self.publisher_name)
```

views.py

```
def addbook(request):
    if request.POST:
        first_name = request.POST.get('first_name')
        last_name = request.POST.get('last_name')
        email = request.POST.get('email')
        age = request.POST.get('age')
    author = Author(first_name = first_name,last_name = last_name,email=email,age=age)
        author=author.save()
        book_name = request.POST.get('book_name')
        publisher_name = request.POST.get('publisher_name')
    #Book.author_id=author
        #author_id = author_id()
        book=Book.objects.create(book_name=book_name,publisher_name=publisher_name,author_id)
    book.save()
    return redirect('/index/')
    else:
        return render_to_response('addbook.html',context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

index.html/templates

```
table border="0" cellpadding='8' cellspacing='10'>
    <tr>
        <td align="right" colspan="8"><a href="/addbook/">Add Book</a></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <th>Book Id</>
    <th>Book name</th>
    <th>Publication name</th>
    <th>Author Id</th>
    <th>First Name</th>
    <th>Last Name</th>
    <th>E Mail</th>
    <th>Age</th>
    </tr>
    {% for book in books %}
    <tr>
       <td>{{ book.book_id }}</td>
       <td>{{ book.book_name }}</td>
       <td>{{ book.publisher_name }}</td>
       <td>{{ book.author_id }}</td>

       {% for author in authors %}  
         <td>{{author.first_name}} </td><td>{{author.last_name}}</td>
         <td>{{author.email}}</td>
         <td>{{author.age}}</td>
           {% endfor %}
             <td><a href="/editbook/{{ book.book_id}}">Edit</a></td>
             <td><a href="/deletebook/{{ book.book_id}}">Delete</a></td>
        {% endfor %}
```

here how to assign foreign key value in Book class for "author" or author_id field,please give the assign procedure.i am not able to ssign values to forreign key field...how to assign or if any other feature available please explain me

Comment: 1. Fix your indentation. 2. Fix your language: English may not be your first language, but there's no excuse for using "plz" instead of "Please", etc. 3. "It's not working" is not helpful. What happens? What errors do you get? Post the traceback. 4. One question per post, please.

Comment: sir i am not able to insert the data into database through web page,the error is "IntegrityError at /addbook/" please help me sir,if you feel this code is not correct you can give me a correct code for learning the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is this:

```
author = Author(first_name = first_name,last_name = last_name,email=email,age=age)
author=author.save()
```

`save()` doesn't actually return anything, even though I believe it should. Change it to simply:

```
author = Author(first_name = first_name,last_name = last_name,email=email,age=age)
author.save()
book.author = author
book.save()
```

And now you have your author, that you can assign to `book.author`.

Also, while I'm here, you should learn about [reverse relations](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#related-objects). The following method is not needed:

```
def books(self):
    return Book.objects.filter(author=self)
```

Because you can do this instead:

```
author.book_set.all()
```

Answer (score 1):

The Integrity error is due to the null value is passed to author_id column of Book table. check this line `book=Book.objects.create(book_name=book_name,publisher_name=publisher_name,author_id)`

If u want to insert the same author id into book table, either you can use

> django-signals

or you have to fetch the latest author id from Author table by querying with some unique parameters (say email id value) and pass this id to the Books table

Comment: can you please show me the code  to fetch the data from Author table with some parameters